# Is there an open-source VS2012 test adapter for gtest?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, open-source, googletest

I'm looking for a Visual Studio 2012 [test adapter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/31/writing-a-visual-studio-2012-unit-test-adapter.aspx) to work with Google Test C++ unit testing. Currently using gtest 1.6, but I'm happy with an answer for any version.
In addition, I want to use a test runner that is open source.

At the time of asking, the only gtest adapter I've found is [Google Test Adapter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f00c0f72-ac71-4c80-bf8b-6fe381548031) in the VS Gallery, but it is closed source.

Q: Is there an open source gtest adapter out there for VS2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if the question still needs an answer, but there is an open source Adapter:

https://github.com/markusl/GoogleTestRunner

It seems to do what the other test adapter does, with some differences:

The Testadapter searches for a string in the executable if it contains Google tests.
The Testrunner calls executables that match a certain regex.

The testrunner is written in F#, which seems to limit the number of contributors.

Comment: Thanks @majo, thanks for drawing my attention to the arrival of this project.  (Over time I expect there will be more open source runners for VS 2012/2013/+, but your answer is good so it will stand as the accepted answer.)

Comment: If anyone knows what the regex is, or what the rules are, or where the user guide is or any kind of readme explaining how to use it, that would be great.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to find one.